# Updating multiple records in a RESTful API

Tags: rest

I would like to know if there is RESTful way to handle updating multiple records with one request where you don't know the ids of the records to update.

Example:

You have resource `/jobs`. Say you are able list these jobs in the following way `GET /jobs?sort=priority&inprogress=false&limit=10` This will return you a list of 10 jobs that are not in progress in priority order.

Now say you want change the state of those jobs to inprogress=true. What would be a RESTful way of achieving this? Obviously you could perform a GET and then update each of those individually but you may have another process that has already grabbed those between you doing the GET and making the update. Then you'll get a failed request because those have already been updated, which is the main thing I want to avoid.

Would it be RESTful to perform an update based on filtering like a GET request e.g

```
PATCH /jobs?sort=priority&inprogress=false&limit=10

{[op:"replace", path:"/inprogress", value:true]}
```

So that this would update the first 10 jobs that are not in progress in priority order, changing them to be inprogress and returning them.

Is this RESTful? Or is there a better way to achieve this in a RESTful way?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

After reading the comments I realize that the command to update the resources really is PATCH, so this answer do not applies. Sorry for the confusion.

---

In Rest definition GET (and also PUT) operations must be idempotent : it means that (see [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html))

> "the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request:

(so when using idempotent operations your client application could repeat any call with the confidence it will not have unexpected results)

The way you pretend to use GET clearly does not follows this restriction, you must use a POST to get this "stopped" processes.

Also I would use some different resource to clearly differentiate this operation: something like

```
POST /activate-jobs?sort=priority&limit=10
```

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with REST. REST supports the usage of standards (uniform interface / self-descriptive messages), and the [HTTP method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2) is a standard...
You don't have to use a different URL, it is okay with the same.

Comment: @inf3rno If you don't specify another thing, and use the common HTTP methods, it is understood that you are referring to HTTP Rest implementation. In that implementation the GET, HEAD, PUT and DELETE methods must be idempotent, so his intended use of GET does not followed that specification. And about the URI: I don't say he must use another URI, that was only a recommendation. I'm sure you will agree that is a good practice to use names for actions that describe what that action do.

Comment: I agree, but the client should not know anything about the structure of the URL, you have to add some metadata, for example IANA link relations to the links, and check those in order to decide which to follow. I guess Chris does not even use links (HATEOAS), so this is not even a REST service, just some RPC which uses HTTP standards...

PATCH is not an idempotent method, so it could be used for what he wants.

Comment: You are right: to verify that the interface follows the HATEOAS principle there are much more things involved. But you can only suppose he does not use link relations, because he does not shows the "rest" of the interface... I was only remarking the first place where it does not followed the HTTP Rest principles (leaving apart the divergence between GET and PATCH... )

Comment: I'm not sure how my GET request is not idempotent? It is not impacting the state of the data in any way. The PATCH request is what would be updating the data. The PATCH also happens to return the updated data. This interface doesn't currently exist, I'm currently in the design phase

Comment: Sorry understood it wrong. I have updated the answer.